# If $L \otimes_K L \cong \oplus_{i=1}^n L_i \cong \oplus_{i=1}^n L,$ why is the kernel of the multiplication map all but one of the $L_i$?

Tags: galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Here $L/K$ is a Galois extension where $L = K[\theta]$ with Galois group $G$. Then if $f$ is the minimal polynomial of $\theta$ which has roots $\theta_i$, then $L \otimes_K L \cong \oplus L[x]/(x-\theta_i)$. Now let $m: L \otimes_K L \to L$ is the multiplication map on the generators.

I'm reading Algebraic Number Fields by Gerald Janusz and he makes the claim that the kernel of the map is all but one of the $L_i$ with no explanation, so I feel like I might be missing something obvious. But on the other hand, I've tried for a half hour and can't find anything. Any insights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  isomorphism $L \otimes_K L \cong \oplus L[x]/(x-\theta_i)\cong \oplus L_i$ where each $L_i=L$ is the induced by the map $p(\theta)\otimes\beta \mapsto ( p(\theta_1)\beta, \cdots,p(\theta_n)\beta)$ where $p(x)\in K[x]$ and $\beta \in L$, so the map $m:\oplus L_i\to L $ would  take  $( p(\theta_1)\beta, \cdots,p(\theta_n)\beta)$ to $p(\theta)\beta$,  but remember that $\theta$ is exactly one of the $\theta_i$'s thus this map is just the $i$-th projection, and therfore its kernel is all but one $L_i$.